# How to get test results data to members of my team that don't have a Visual Studio License?

Tags: load-testing, visualstudio

I'm not asking if the load and web testing tool is good.  Please don't start a flame war.

I have load test results that I been to make available to others, some with versions of VS without load testing and some without any VS IDE at all.

It looks like this isn't easy and to do so I'd have to create my own bespoke solution in order for others to explore the data as I can on VS.

Is there a (reasonably simple) way to allow other consumers of the data to explore it as I can without buying everyone a license for the Enterprise edition?

It seems that using this tool isn't too useful if all my data is jailed and requires a fair bit of new development to jail break it.

Comment: not sure what you are asking for here, so you want to know if the VS enterprise will work for your testing needs? I would just download a trial to see the features and see if you like it

Comment: No, I have it.  I use it, it's very powerful and does everything I want from a functional perspective.  The problem is sharing those metrics afterwards.

Comment: So you use it for what kind of testing? and are you getting results to VS currently? Visual Studio has a lot of stats and metrics that are exportable to excel or other programs

Comment: Load testing.  When the results are viewed in Visual Studio I can lots of functionality to drill down to request and view graphs and aggregations.  Unfortunately, I can't share that with anyone.

Comment: The Excel exports are only for trend analysis or comparisons.  I just want to share the results from a specific test run with the same functionality I get in VS.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817729.aspx look here you can copy and paste the summary information into word, this might be useful to your cause

Comment: That could work, as long as the users don't need VS Enterprise to open it.  Thanks.  I'll give it a try in the office tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio offers a lot of different ways to grab the summary information from the application and paste it into other microsoft programs like excel/word. I would recommend going to [Paste into word for VS summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817729.aspx) with this you can save the word document and email it out to whomever you want to read the information without them being required to have a VS license.